# Why does Fibonacci identity $3 f_n = f_{n+2} + f_{n-2}$? This is from Proofs That Really Count.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorial-proofs, tiling

I am reading the book "Proofs That Really Count" by Benjamin and Quinn.

In chapter $1$, they establish that:

$f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$, and $f_1 = 1$, $f_2 = 2$, $f_3 = 3$, $f_4 = 5$, etc.

The chapter establishes that $f_n$ is the combination of ways to place dominoes and squares on $n$-tiled board. For example, $f_4=5$, so there are $5$ ways to place dominoes and squares on a $4$-tiled board:

1. ▫▫▫▫
2. ▫▫▭
3. ▫▭▫
4. ▭▫▫
5. ▭▭

The first chapter continues with examples of how to prove identities with $f_n$ based on tiles and squares arguments.

---

In Chapter $1$, Identity $7$, they give prove this identity using tiles and squares argument:

$3 f_n = f_{n+2} + f_{n-2}$

The argument goes as follows:

You have a $n$-tiled board, and it can be converted into either a $(n+2)$ tiled board or a $(n-2)$ tiled board in the following three ways:

Given an $n$ tiled board:

1. Add two squares to get $n+2$.
2. Add one domino to get $n+2$.
3. 

a. If the last position of the $n$ tiled board is a square, add a domino before the last square to get $n+2$.

b. If the last position of the $n$ tiled board is a domino, remove the domino to get $n-2$.

The number of ways to tile either $(n+2)$ or $(n-2)$ tiled board is $f_{n+2} + f_{n-2}$. That concludes the proof of $3 f_n = f_{n+2} + f_{n-2}$.

The part that confuses me about this proof is in case $3$. If you assume that an $n$ tiled board's last position has a square, doesn't that mean that the ways to tile such a board is actually $f_{n-1}$? Similarly for when the last position is a domino, then wouldn't it always be $f_{n-2}$?

Maybe I'm missing a deeper intuition here about this combinatoric proof?

Edit: updating the wording to more accurately reflect the problem.

Comment: You are right that "There are $f_{n-1}$ ways to tile a $n-$board such that the last tile is a square (and vice versa)". $\quad$ What they are trying to establish here is a bijection between the $3f_n$ board arrangements, and the $f_{n-2} + f_{n+2}$ ways of tiling a $n+2$ and a $n-1$ board. The do so by breaking down the $f_{n-2}$ ways into A) last is a domino $= f_n$ ways, B) last two are a tile $=f_n$ ways, C) last two are a tile then a domino $ = f_n - f_{n-2}$ ways.   [They explained C is by constructing 3a and 3b. There are some details to be checked, like ensuring that truly a bijection].

Comment: Honestly, I'm more concerned by "You have three $n$-tiled boards, so there are $3 f_n$ ways to tile them."

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error in the way I worded the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the very first line, "You have three $n$-tiled boards, so there are $3f_n$ ways to tile them," I am no longer following the argument.  Treated literally, there are $f_n^3$ ways to tile three boards of length $n$, but this then throws the entire rest of the argument off the rails.

Here's how I'd present it: (hopefully the differences distinguish it enough from that given in the book to give you a second look)

For a fixed $n$-tiled board and an $i\in \{1,2,3\}$, we do the following:

1. If $i=1$, then add a domino to the end of the board, making an $(n+2)$-tiled board that ends in a domino.
2. If $i=2$, then add two squares to the end of the board, making an $(n+2)$-tiled board that ends in two squares.
3. If $i=3$, then we look at the last element in our board.  If it is a domino, then we remove it, giving an $(n-2)$-tiled board with no restrictions.  If it is a square, then we put a domino right before the square, making an $(n+2)$-tiled board that ends in a domino and then a square.

Yes, in the third case, we are implicitly using $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$, and in fact, we effectively are using the fact that the $(n-1)$-tiled boards correspond to the $(n+2)$-tiled boards that end in a domino followed by a square.

The main point, however, is that the $(n+2)$-tiled boards may be partitioned into three mutually exclusive types: Those that end in a domino ($f_n$ of these), those that end in two squares ($f_n$ of these), and those that end in a domino followed by a square ($f_{n-1}$ of these).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation -- the last paragraph in particular was very helpful.

A follow up question: In cases 1 and 2, the proof says we add either a domino or two squares *at the end*. Similarly, case 3 is about the end of the tiles. Why does it have to be at the end? Why can't we, say, add a domino or two squares in the middle of an $n$ tile board?

Comment: @SamadLotia We need whatever procedure we use to yield each $(n+2)$-tiled board in one and only one way.  If you consistently add to the end, we can do this.  Similarly if we consistently add to the front it'll work.  If you want to propose a method of doing this in the middle, we can talk about it, but it would be much harder.  For instance, we cannot simply put it in the 2nd and 3rd spots without considering that the first piece might be a domino.